# Subset of a complement

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ a subset. Suppose I know that $V\subseteq X$ is such that $V\subseteq X\setminus A$ and $V$ is open

Can I conclude $V\subseteq X\setminus\overline{A}$? Why?

Equivalently, I tried to prove $\overline{A}\subseteq X\setminus V$.

If $x\in A$ then $x\in X\setminus V$ by hypothesis. But I can't really conclude the case $x\in \overline{A}\setminus A$, i guess I should use the fact that $V$ is open. Where precisely? Is this statement even true?

Comment: Did you try to prove it? Please add what have you tried.

Comment: I added what I proved so far, very little. Will you please give it a look now? This lemma would ease a lot of proofs

Answer (score 2):

Since $V$ is open, $X\setminus V$ by definition is closed. Also, remember that the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$, or equivalently, the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$. So if $X\setminus V$ is a closed set that contains $A$, it must also contain $\overline{A}$.